# What is the package declaration of a drl file placed in C:/Users/ path

Tags: drools

I have a sample drl file placed in C:/Users that am trying to load into KieSession. what should be the package declaration in the drl file?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Packages in Drools 7 (and later) work just like packages in Java. They describe the folders relative to the classpath that you have to traverse to get to the resource.

Therefore, what you use depends on what you put on your classpath. If the 'C:' drive is on your classpath, then your package would be 'Users'.